# Pass probabilities to kdeplot

Tags: python, seaborn, kdeplot

Suppose I want to plot the following data using `sns.kdeplot`:

```
np.random.seed(42)
x = [np.random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(10)]

x
[6, 3, 7, 4, 6, 9, 2, 6, 7, 4]
```

[image]

But now, instead of having each value, suppose I have the probability of each one:

```
# y is a pd.Series
y
6    0.3
7    0.2
4    0.2
9    0.1
3    0.1
2    0.1
```

Is it possible to build the `kdeplot` from these probabilities?

I think that seaborn probably calculate these values and thus I think it might be possible

Comment: There is a `weights` parameter (on v0.11.0+) that may be useful but I am not exactly  that sure what you are looking for with "build kdeplot from these probabilities". In general I would say that a KDE plot is not a good approach for visualization the distribution of a variable that takes a small number of discrete values.

Comment: Great, I think that works. My original data is a lot larger than this, I just used this small dataset as an example! @mwaskom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with the `weights` parameter of `kdeplot` (added in v0.11.0), something like

```
sns.kdeplot(x=x, weights=y)
```